# Calling stored procedures remotely on SQL Server Express (AWS RDS)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

I'm trying to call a procedure on Amazon RDS that is located in a SQL Server Express database. SQL Server Express does not have a task scheduler, so the closest I have got to a solution is to use an EC2 instance I have running and create a batch file to which I can attach a statement like the one below:

```
 sqlcmd -Q "exec myproc" -SERVERDNSADDRESS -DATABASENAME.
```

But everywhere I read says that RDS doesn't allow this. Are there any Amazon services I can use to fill the gap? How do I go about executing this procedure on a daily basis? Should I be using AWS Data pipeline for such a simple task, and if so are there any tutorials out there (besides the AWS ones) that can help?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I am trying to avoid having an instance just doing this. I have stumbled across AWS Data Pipeline, but can only seem to track down MySQL procedure calls. I have thus put it to the community here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637926/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-with-data-pipeline-in-shellcomman

Comment: With regards to AWS Pipeline, this page appears to explain how you define a connection to SQL Server: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-rdsdatabase.html, and this page appears to define how you call some SQL against that predefined connection (which I guess is linked with the `id` attribute http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-sqlactivity.html. If you follow it through and it works, please post back the solution in detail here and you'll be a legend!! ;)

Comment: Thanks so much, will give it a go today!

Comment: Any luck? I'm curious to know how if this works but don't have time to try it